# Speech Recognition(Speech To Text) is not working in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean, speech-to-text

I have [device](http://wiki.ambedded.com.tw/index.php?title=In-Vehicle_Computer) which has android 4.2.2 is installed on it. Is is not supporting SpeechRecognition api. I tried one speech to text application and it is giving "Speech to Text doesnot support in your device" error. I also tried installing Google Search application and tried to search using voice icon, but it is giving following exception:

```
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403): java.lang.RuntimeException:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  Couldn't load google_recognizer_jni from loader  dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/app/com.google.android.googlequick searchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260-minAPI16.apk,libraryPath=/data/app- lib/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260- minAPI16]: findLibrary returned null
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at emt.afterExecute(PG:487)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403): Caused by:  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  Couldn't load google_recognizer_jni from loader  dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/app/com.google.android.googlequick searchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260-minAPI16.apk,libraryPath=/data/app- lib/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260- minAPI16]: findLibrary returned null
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:160)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     ... 4 more
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403): Caused by:  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load google_recognizer_jni from loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/app/com.google.android.googlequick searchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260-minAPI16.apk,libraryPath=/data/app- lib/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-4.0.26.1499465.arm-300400260- minAPI16]: findLibrary returned null
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at gjr.aGA(PG:39)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at gjo.a(PG:84)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at err.run(PG:102)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201( ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
02-13 21:58:48.077: E/AndroidRuntime(9403):     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try copying `system/lib/libgoogle_recognizer_jni.so` from https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0P1Z8DuTunwN3pJNEsxa0JQYWs/edit to your `/system/lib` directory. Make sure you also run `chmod 644 libgoogle_recognizer_jni.so`.

Comment: I am having this issue on Genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) .  Is this rarely an issue on real devices?

Comment: @toobsco42 Does this not work for you on Genymotion? Is there no way to boot the system? I'd imagine you just `adb shell` into it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, this is because your `.so` native library is not inside the APK in the `lib` folder.

Check out this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader).