# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView

Tags: android, android-inflate

Below is the error I get whenever I try to run the app..
I am using **pdfViewer library** to display a PDF.

```
   stackTrace:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.justswipe.document/com.justswipe.document.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at com.justswipe.document.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.justswipe.document.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/app-release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmodpdfium.so"
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
   at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.<clinit>(PdfiumCore.java:19)
   at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.<init>(PDFView.java:316)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.justswipe.document.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5979) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Below is the **xml file** where I use the library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.justswipe.document.MainActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:text="/" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error occurs only when I sign the APK and install it in the system/app folder of my rooted phone.

The APK runs normally if it is not signed. Can anyone help..? I have tried using the suggestions given in other answers none of them seem to work for me.

Comment: check "com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView" is is there in your project using ctrl + click.

Comment: Yep its there i can navigate through the class.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader

Comment: i havent used ndk i followed the readme given in the lib https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: @AkshayShah Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No i did not but you can try the solution to the question i asked at git..check https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/84 may be these should help