# Error while running cocoa2dx project

Tags: android, cocoa, android-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

**Manifest**

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"> 
<!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so --> 
<meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="MyGame" />
<activity ............../> </intent-filter> </activity> 
</application>
```

**Error:**

```
com.xxx.xxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.xxx.xxxxxxx, PID: 15913 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.xxxxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] 
>couldn't find "libMyGame.so"                                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
                                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
                                                                   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:248)
                                                                   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:264)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

it redirect me in file

> Cocos2dxActivity.java:248 in code line **System.loadLibrary(libName);**

I am stuck with this error. Help me.

I am using cocos2d-x-3.13

```
Android NDK, Revision 12 
Latest SDK
Android-studio 2.1.3
python 2.7.12
apache-ant 1.9.7
JDK 1.8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u share ur manifest ? Or just have a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader

Comment: `<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        
        <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
       ** <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                   android:value="MyGame" />**

        <activity
           ............../>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>`

here is my menifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
couldn't find "libMyGame.so"
```

This error happens because you didn't compiled for the architecture you are trying to test on.

Change to this in Application.mk file:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Then recompile and test.

Comment: I have tried with 
`app-abi=armeabi-v7a armeabi x86 `
 It works properly.

Could we call like this for multiple architecture ?

Comment: `jni/../../../Classes/Menu/MenuScene.h:28: error: undefined reference to 'MenuSce
ne::MenuScene()'`

I am getting error like this do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Without seeing whats on line 28 and the file contents I can't really say what the problem is. Maybe post the header contents so I can see.

Comment: Thank you for help. 

I have resolve that error, but when I am running this in my device it only seeing blank black screen, nothing happens further. Does this error either for any CPU architecture or anything other. It would be great if you could help me. I am stuck.

Comment: This might be a problem in your code, is there any error reported in Logcat?

Comment: I have one file named **MenuScene.h**(which giving error in line 28) which create MenuScene. As I have send you previous error it not able to create MenuScene. Code in that Line is 
`CREATE_FUNC(MenuScene);`

Comment: Have you edited Android.mk and included the MenuScene.cpp file in LOCAL_SRC_FILES ?

Comment: how to recompile? I have the same issue but changing APP_ABI solves nothing cause it looks like android studio doesn't compile native code at all

Comment: @fnc12 - you have to compile first in terminal using cocos cli. Try: cocos compile -p android --android-studio --ap android-25 --no-apk and make sure you have android-25 sdk installed in android studio.