# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[...]couldn't find "libnfc_nci_jni_cxd22xx.so"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

It seems to be a really specific error I got in Android Studio which occurs when I try to let my app run on my Huawei device (HW-01K).

The error looks like this:

```
ReportTools             system_server                        E  This is not beta user build
HsmCoreServiceImpl      com.huawei.systemserver              E  onTransact in code is: 102
ProcessInfoCollector    system_server                        E  getProcessInfo: failed to find this proc 
com.android.nf          pid-22562                            E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
NfcNci                  pid-22562                            E  NfcApplication error: new NfcService
AndroidRuntime          pid-22562                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.android.nfc, PID: 22562
                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.huawei.nfc.jar", zip file "/system/app/NfcNci_45/NfcNci_45.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/NfcNci_45/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnfc_nci_jni_cxd22xx.so"
                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1672)
                                                             at com.android.nfc.dhimpl.SonyNativeNfcManager.<clinit>(SonyNativeNfcManager.java:67)
                                                             at com.android.nfc.NfcService.<init>(NfcService.java:1395)
                                                             at com.android.nfc.NfcApplication.onCreate(NfcApplication.java:99)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1162)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6566)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:267)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1963)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

The error specifications could not help me to find the place where this library "libnfc_nci_jni_cxd22xx.so" is demanded or described. Apparently, it is needed for some NFC function my app does not need and has never specified any usage of it (Searched my entire project for "NFC").

When I tried to CTRL + Click the Runtime class written in the first line under the actual error ("at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)") I get two options to choose. One Runtime class of the the Android API 33 Platform and one of the embedded JDK which is already depreciated. This is weird to me and dont know if that is supposed to be like that or if this is related to the error.

There is a similar question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader). I used some of the solutions like setting abiFilters and setting a flag in the gradle property file which is described there but it did not help. I think the nature of my error is different. I hope so in order to post a significant question on this platform.

I don't find anything to this awesome library in this error. I am stuck here for a while already. Please let me know if you want to see specific code sections of my project. Thank you for your attention!!